# AJAX - Run PHP function on button click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a simple PHP based counter Wordpress function that updates the user meta every time the page is loaded.

What I would like to do is only run this function when a particular button is clicked.

My button markup

```
<a class="button" id="interaction-count" href="#">Interaction</a>
```

My current PHP function (Which currently runs, and updates the user meta, on each page load)

```
function setCvDownloads($postID) {
    $count_key = 'download_count';
    $count = get_user_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_user_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_user_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_user_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
```

Is is possible to run this when the `interaction-count` button is clicked instead? I assume some AJAX would be involved? If someone couple point me in the right direction that would be great

Comment: Correct - it is possible to run it when the `interaction-count` button is clicked and also yes, ajax would probably be the best option.

Comment: From Where you will get the `$myValue` value...

Comment: And another note you have not used `$myValue` anywhere in your function.

Comment: @NareshKumar.P Yes sorry, it was an old value, I have edited my question

Comment: That means you can choose the ajax method and it will work fine.. Will post up the ajax function asap. Have a check of it..

Answer (score 1):

Usage of the Ajax is the best option that will proceed.

```
<a class="button" id="interaction-count" href="#" onclick="setCvDownloads(<?php echo $post->ID);">Interaction</a>
```

You need to pass the post ID in that function since you have used it over to the function.

**Ajax:**

Make sure your file-path is correct in the URL of the Ajax syntax or else t will not work.

```
function setCvDownloads(a)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/savedata.php",
      data: "&post_id="+a,
      success:function(html)
      {
         // here you can provide if you need success notifications or as per your wish.
      }
    });
}
```

**savedata.php**

```
<?php
include('../../wp-config.php'); // Ensure that your wp-config file is connected here correctly.
$post_ID = $_POST['post_id']; // Getting the posted POST ID over ajax here.
$count_key = 'download_count';
    $count = get_user_meta($post_ID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_user_meta($post_ID, $count_key);
        add_user_meta($post_ID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_user_meta($post_ID, $count_key, $count);
    }
?>
```

Comment: The `setCvDownloads` function that I currently have is a PHP function so I assume it wont work in JS?

Comment: @DeanElliott. I have added the Ajax code over to my answer by editing it. Check and let me know. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery. This jQuery code should do it, but you need a PHP file to capture the request.

```
$("#interaction-count").on("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/somephpfile.php",
      data: {},
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do also synchronously, but the best way is surely usin ajax.

So the code, in simple js (without jquery), would be:

```
<input type="button" ... onclick="CallPhpFunction()" />
....
<script>
function CallPhpFunction() {
    var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('POST', 'phpscript.php', true);
    xhttp.send('data=somedata&otherData=someotherdata');
}
</script>
```

In the example I've also show how you can send data to the php script passing it to the send method. That can be used in the php script using $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

for doing this you need to add following code inside wordpress loop

```
<a class="button" id="interaction-count" href="#"
 onclick="increaseMyCount('<?php the_ID();?>')">Interaction</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function increaseMyCount(numb_data)
{
jQuery.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
data: { postid: numb_data, action: 'setcvdownloads' }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
}
</script>
```

and in functions.php of theme file you need to write following code

```
<?php
function setCvDownloads() {
    $count_key = 'download_count';
    $postID=$_POST['postid'];
    $count = get_user_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
    $count = 0;
    //delete_user_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_user_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_user_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
    echo "Saved";
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_setcvdownloads', 'setCvDownloads' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_setcvdownloads', 'setCvDownloads' );
?>
```